# Reading ResourceBundle with uppercase name shows strange behavior

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, resourcebundle

I'm having a really strange problem I don't have any logical explanation for. In essence, I'm trying to read a `CamelCase` `ResourceBundle` through an `UpperCase` name from an external `.jar`. E.g. the `ResourceBundle` is called *MessageBundle* and I read it with *MESSAGEBUNDLE*. The strange behavior I'm experiencing is described below.

Consider the following simple project layout:

[image: ResourceBundleProject]

It basically consists of 2 small projects. The project *ResourceBundleDependency* consist only of a property file. The project *ResourceBundleReader* consists of a property file, a `main` method and it has a dependency to the project *ResourceBundleDependency*.

In the `main` method of `BundleReader`, I try and read both ResourceBundles in 2 ways. Both CamelCase and UpperCase as such:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ResourceBundle readerBundle = PropertyResourceBundle.getBundle("ReaderMessageBundle", Locale.getDefault());
    System.out.println(readerBundle.getString("READER.KEY"));

    ResourceBundle upperReaderBundle = PropertyResourceBundle.getBundle("READERMESSAGEBUNDLE", Locale.getDefault());
    System.out.println(upperReaderBundle.getString("READER.KEY"));

    ResourceBundle depBundle = PropertyResourceBundle.getBundle("DependencyMessageBundle", Locale.getDefault());
    System.out.println(depBundle.getString("DEPENDENCY.KEY"));

    ResourceBundle upperDepBundle = PropertyResourceBundle.getBundle("DEPENDENCYMESSAGEBUNDLE", Locale.getDefault());
    System.out.println(upperDepBundle.getString("DEPENDENCY.KEY"));
}
```

**Finding #1:**

If both projects are open in NetBeans and I run the main method. All works fine and the following is printed:

```
Internal Value
Internal Value
Dependency Value
Dependency Value
```

This is my desired output.

**Finding #2:**

When I close the *ResourceBundleDependency* project in `NetBeans` and run the same method again (I've built the dependency), it locates the file when called in a CamelCase manner but can't find it using the UpperCase manner:

```
Internal Value
Internal Value
Dependency Value
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name DEPENDENCYMESSAGEBUNDLE, locale en_GB
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:845)
    at com.mycompany.resourcebundlereader.BundleReader.main(BundleReader.java:19)
```

It can't be a `Classpath` issue, since the CamelCase property file IS found normally.

**Finding #3:**

The culprit must be `NetBeans`. Instead, I'll build a `.jar` and run that instead. Calling `java -jar ResourceBundleReader-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`, I get the following output:

```
Internal Value
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name READERMESSAGEBUNDLE, locale en_GB
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
        at com.mycompany.resourcebundlereader.BundleReader.main(BundleReader.java:13)
```

Which is even worse? It can't even read the property file from its own `.jar` in uppercase anymore.

**Finding #4:**

The culprit must be `Maven`? Creating a `.jar` without using maven and just adding the dependency jar to the classpath, the issue is the same as the previous. Works fine from `NetBeans`, can't even read its own `ResourceBundle` in UpperCase:

```
java -jar ResourceBundleReader2.jar
Internal Value
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name READERMESSAGEBUNDLE, locale en_GB
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
        at resourcebundlereader2.BundleReader.main(BundleReader.java:13)
```

The [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) and [PropertyResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html) JavaDoc don't really mention anything from resolving by UpperCase. But if it works in one case, why not the other? If it isn't really supported well, could custom `ClassLoader`s resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the case-sensitivity of the underlying "filesystem" (if I may call a jar file a filesystem).

`PropertyResourceBundle.getBundle()` has to load an appropriately named properties file. That means that some code has to lookup the properties file either in the filesystem or in a jar file.

On windows, the filesystem is case insensitiv, so searching for "READERMESSAGEBUNDLE.properties" will find the file named "ReaderMessageBundle.properties".

The linux filesystems and the jar files are case sensitive, so searching for "READERMESSAGEBUNDLE.properties" will find nothing.

---

Will a custom classloader solve your problem? It could, if it's `ClassLoader.getResource(String)` method not just return the URL for `READERMESSAGEBUNDLE.properties` (if it exists) but lists all resources contained in its classpath and tests if any one of them matches the name case-insensitive.